# Block element characters (pmboxdraw) are shown too wide in verbatim and Verbatim (fancyvrb) environments

Tags: symbols, verbatim, fancyvrb

I want to put source code into *verbatim* and *Verbatim* (fancyvrb) environments that uses box-drawing characters from codepage 850 (0xDB, 0xDC, 0xDF) (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850). By using a text editor I converted the source code file to Unicode and created the following minimal example in LaTeX (source code is taken from tube by 3SC (http://www.pouet.net/prod.php?which=3397) FWIW):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pmboxdraw}
\author{Wolfgang Keller}
\title{Minimal example}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
;  (▄) ( ) ▄ ) ( )   256b intro by baze/3SC for Syndeecate 2001   use NASM to
;  ▀█▀ █▄█ ███ ██▄   loveC: thanks, Serzh: eat my socks dude ;]   compile the
;  ( ) ( ) ( ) ( )   e-mail: baze@stonline.sk, web: www.3SC.sk    source code
\end{verbatim}

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
;  (▄) ( ) ▄ ) ( )   256b intro by baze/3SC for Syndeecate 2001   use NASM to
;  ▀█▀ █▄█ ███ ██▄   loveC: thanks, Serzh: eat my socks dude ;]   compile the
;  ( ) ( ) ( ) ( )   e-mail: baze@stonline.sk, web: www.3SC.sk    source code
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

The problem is: the block elements are drawn far too wide - destroying the ASCII art. And the documentation of pmboxdraw (http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pmboxdraw/pmboxdraw.pdf) doesn't really tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option `Block/box` helps, it expects a box template for the Block elements. In this case the block characters should probably occupy the place of a character in typewriter font:

```
\pmboxdrawsetup{
  Block/box={\texttt{0}},
}
```

> [image: Result]

For ASCII art, the block characters should probably occupy the line better, a `\strut` helps then:

```
\pmboxdrawsetup{
  Block/box={\texttt{0}\strut},
}
```

> [image: Result with \strut]