# How to typeset shell like output in Latex

Tags: formatting, unicode, verbatim

I'm trying to achieve a output as shown below with latex

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   32G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   99M  0 part /boot
└─sda2   8:2    0 31,9G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1 55,5M  0 rom
```

The best I can come up with is the above minus the lines indicating the structure of the device-tree

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   32G  0 disk 
  sda1   8:1    0   99M  0 part /boot
  sda2   8:2    0 31,9G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1 55,5M  0 rom
```

is there a way also render thoese symbols missing in my output?

Comment: could you add your example code here, so others can try around.

Comment: yes of course, basically i did try the same as the approved answer but i missed the \usepackage{pmboxdraw} package and used listing instead of verbatim

This is how my code looked like:

`\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   32G  0 disk 
  sda1   8:1    0   99M  0 part /boot
  sda2   8:2    0 31,9G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1 55,5M  0 rom
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pmboxdraw}
\pmboxdrawsetup{
  Block/box={\texttt{0}},
}
\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   32G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   99M  0 part /boot
└─sda2   8:2    0 31,9G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1 55,5M  0 rom
\end{verbatim}


\end{document}
```

see [Block element characters (pmboxdraw) are shown too wide in verbatim and Verbatim (fancyvrb) environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108127/block-element-characters-pmboxdraw-are-shown-too-wide-in-verbatim-and-verbatim)